Try to use Power pivot combined with excel to filter the results using VBA syntax, but it cannot be filtered
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim filterText As String
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim cfB As CubeField

    ' 定義工作表與範圍
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ws1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ws2")
    
    ' 讀取篩選文字
    filterText = ws1.OLEObjects("Textbox1").Object.Text
    
    ' 創建樞紐分析表快取
    Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:=ThisWorkbook.Connections("pi1"))
    
    ' 檢查是否成功設置 PivotCache
    If pc Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "無法設置現有的 PivotCache。"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' 設定樞紐分析表
    Set ws = Worksheets("ws2")
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables("LKK")
    
    ' 設置欄位A
    Set cfB = pt.CubeFields("[ex].[A]")  ' 欄位名稱為 "A"
    cfB.Orientation = xlRowField
    pt.PivotFields(1).Subtotals(1) = False
    
    ' 設置欄位B
    Set cfB = pt.CubeFields("[ex].[B]") ' 欄位名稱為 "B"
    cfB.Orientation = xlRowField
    pt.PivotFields(2).Subtotals(1) = False
    
    ' 設置欄位C
    Set cfB = pt.CubeFields("[ex].[C]")  ' 欄位名稱為 "C"
    cfB.Orientation = xlRowField
    pt.PivotFields(3).Subtotals(1) = False
    
    ' 篩選樞紐分析表資料
   ' On Error Resume Next
    cfB.ClearAllFilters
    cfB.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:=filterText
    'On Error GoTo 0

    ' 更新樞紐分析表顯示
    pt.RefreshTable
    
    ' 完成設置
    Set pt = Nothing
    Set cfB = Nothing
    Set pc = Nothing
    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
End Sub


cfB.ClearAllFilters
 cfB.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:=filterText

cfB.ClearAllFilters and cfB.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:=filterText in this code are used to filter fields in the pivot analysis table. When you execute this code, you may encounter errors, usually because the program cannot find the pivot table column named [ex].[A], [ex].[B], or [ex].[C] bit, or the filter conditions are set incorrectly.
